# Raspberry Pi instantly logs me out

Tags: raspbian, pi-2

When I ssh into it, it instantly drops the connection. When I hook it up to the monitor it accepts my login, shows the last login time (about 30 seconds before this attempt) the kernel version, the copyright, and warranty information, and then it instantly dumps me back to the login prompt. I've tried power cycling the pi and I get the same response.

Comment: Is the Pi kicking you out, or is your network connection dropping? You can get this if your wifi signal is weak and many packets get dropped.  That could be wifi to your Pi or wifi to the machine from which you initiate the ssh.

Comment: The pi kicks me out. When I log in locally it logs in, shows the last successful log in time, kernel version, etc... and then goes straight back to a login prompt

Comment: Try running "ssh <RPi> /bin/bash". If that gives you a shell prompt, then there's something wrong with your login environment. Try renaming likely dot files (e.g. .login , .bashrc, .bash_profile, .profile) and try logging in again.

Comment: I can't comment due to insufficient reputation, however I have the same issue.
Is your Pi overclocked?

Answer (score 1):

Try re imaging your sd card and the problem still persists try changing the sd card. Otherwise check if the pi is getting extremely warm.

Comment: It doesn't seem very warm, but I was trying to avoid having to rebuild. This pi is my unity controller.

Comment: You could always copy the files off the sd card....

Answer (score 0):

Is ssh enabled on your pi? You may have to enable it in the raspberry pi configuration or raspi-config. If it is enabled, then do you have a firewall running on your pi? Sometimes firewalls on raspberry pi's will disable ssh. If you turn off the firewall temporarily then the problem may be solved. Hope that helps you. :)